# How can I figure out which theme is used by the user?

Tags: application-development

I use Ubuntu's toolbar theme (context) in my application which is black for Ambiance and grey for Radiance. So I have got two icon packs (a white and a black one), but how can I figure out which theme is used by the user? So I'll can write an if statement for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can type in terminal:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

Or in Python:

```
from gi.repository import Gio
theme=Gio.Settings.new('org.gnome.desktop.interface').get_string('gtk-theme')
```

Comment: This is a command or what? Please explain it a little bit. :)

Comment: `robin@RobinJ:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme` outputs `'Ambiance'` in my case. If the user uses Radiance it will output that.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a stock icon, it will always use the icon of the theme which was chosen by the user.

Also: [Why do the GNOME symbolic icons appear darker in a running application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148955/why-do-the-gnome-symbolic-icons-appear-darker-in-a-running-application/)

Comment: Yeah, but I need own icons.